# ActiveMQ shared file system master slave on NTFS

Tags: activemq-classic, ntfs

I'm trying to setup shared file system master slave ActiveMQ on NTFS drive. But it seems that file lock doesn't work on NTFS. I tried to change and save content of the "lock" file with notepad and it's changeable. I can't delete this file while ActiveMQ is running but able to change. So second ActiveMQ instance doesn't see this file lock and uses the same kahadb.

Is it known issue or there are workarounds for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a bug...see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3273